# Deleting printer programmatically

Tags: winapi

I want to remove a mapped printer and P/Invoking the following

```
[DllImport("winspool.drv", EntryPoint = "DeletePrinterConnection", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
private static extern int DeletePrinterConnection(string pName);
```

When I use just the printer name or (PrinterName on server) I keep getting the printer name is invalid.

What name is this expecting as input?

***Update 1***

```
[DllImport("winspool.drv", EntryPoint = "DeletePrinterConnection")]
private static extern int DeletePrinterConnectionA(string pName);
```

DeletePrinterConnectionW (Unicode) and DeletePrinterConnectionA (ANSI)

```
int r = DeletePrinterConnectionA(printer);
if (!r.Equals(0))
{
   throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
}
```

This throws back Operation completed successfully - but it didn't and the printer is still there.

Return value

If the function succeeds, the return value is a nonzero value.
If the function fails, the return value is zero.

Answer (score 0):

From MSDN:

> *pName [in]*
>
> Pointer to a null-terminated string that specifies the name
> of the printer connection to delete.

[DeletePrinterConnection function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183542(v=vs.85).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, because it was a mapped printer the name it's expecting is

```
\\server\printer name
```